# How to run this Link List program?

Tags: java

```
 package uni;

    import java.util.*;

    public class Link {

        public int data;
        public Link next;
        int iData;
        Link header = null;
        Link idata;

        public Link(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void LinkDisplay() {
            System.out.println("Data: " + data);
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();

            int num;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter data");
                num = input.nextInt();
                linkedList.insertLink(num);
            }

            linkedList.DiaplayAll();
            linkedList.deleteFirst();

        }

    }

    class LinkedList {

        public Link first;
        Link header = null;

        public void insertLink(int data) {
            Link newLink = new Link(data);
            newLink.next = first;
            first = newLink;
        }

        public void DiaplayAll() {
            Link current = first;
            while (current != null) {
                current.LinkDisplay();
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
// delete method is called

        public int deleteFirst() // delete first item
        {
    // (assumes list not empty)
            Link current = header; // save reference to link
            header = header.next; // delete it: first-->old next
            return current.data; `enter code here`// return deleted link
        }

  }
```

This is Link List program. I have run this code several times but it gives exception in line 45 and 74. Code is working well except deletion method. There are probably two errors; 1st in deletion method call and second in when it deletes the node.

Please guide me what are these errors and why are the occured.

---

Here is the output:

```
debug:
Enter data
100
Enter data
45
Enter data
10
Data: 100
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at uni.LinkedList.deleteFirst(Link.java:74)
    at uni.Link.main(Link.java:45)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: could you please post the exact errors that you receive?

Comment: when you are calling header.next, header is equal to null, so it gives a nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list may contain just one `header` node, you should check it when deleting a node:

```
public int deleteFirst() {
    if (header == null)
        return -1;      // <- -1 indicates that list is empty, but it is better to throw RuntimeException here
    Link current = header; 
    header = header.next == null ? null : header.next; // <- check if header.next exists
    return current.data; 
}
```

Comment: "header = header.next == null ? null : header.next; // <- check if header.next exists" can you please explain me the exact meaning of this line

Comment: @ZainFarooq this is called ternary operator. `A = condition ? B : C` is shortcut for `if (condition) {A = B;} else {A = C;}`. Here, condition is `header.next == null`